powerbiclient QuickVisualize issue when run from a jupyter-hub
power-bi integration with jupyter is working flawlessly when run from a local jupyter-notebook:
from powerbiclient import QuickVisualize, get_dataset_config, Report
from powerbiclient.authentication import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication

auth = DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication()
pbi_visualize = QuickVisualize(get_dataset_config(df.reset_index()), auth)

However the same code when worked on jupyter-hub (docker container), it's giving below error:
Failed to load model class 'QuickVisualizeModel' from module 'powerbi-jupyter-client'
Error: No version of module powerbi-jupyter-client is registered

I confirmed that powerbiclient / QuickVisualize is installed properly.
poetry dependencies:
powerbiclient = "3.1.1"
ipympl = "0.9.3"
ipython = "^8.21.0"
jinja2 = "^3.1.2"

Moreover, widgets like ipywidgets are satisfied.
Is there any setting / env variable or jupyter widget / extensions missing?
